# How can I extract something from an expression and assign it without changing the expression?

Tags: pattern-matching, core-language

I am researching how to extract a certain value from an expression by using a pattern mechanism without actually changing the original expression.

The paragraph above could be very ambiguous, so here is an example.
The aim here is to extract the number 4 before t and assign it to Symbol j.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

n = 3 Cos[4 t + 2]
(* 3 Cos[2 + 4 t] *)

n = 3 Cos[4 t + 2] /. _ Cos[r_ t + _] :> (k = r)
(* 4 *)
k
(* 4 *)
n
(* 4 *)
```

But unfortunately, it assigns 4 to n as well. Even if I use `;` after `k = r`, it assigns `Null` to `n` as you can see below.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n = 3 Cos[4 t + 2]
(* 3 Cos[2 + 4 t] *)    
n = 3 Cos[4 t + 2] /. _ Cos[r_ t + _] :> (k = r;)
k
(* 4 *)
n
```

How to extract 4 and assign it to `k` without having the original expression changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parenthesize:

```
In[4]:= (n = 3 Cos[4 t + 2]) /. _ Cos[r_ t + _] :> (k = r);

In[5]:= {n, k}

Out[5]= {3 Cos[2 + 4 t], 4}
```

Equivalently, use full form:

```
In[8]:= n =.; k =.

In[9]:= ReplaceAll[n = 3 Cos[4 t + 2], _ Cos[r_ t + _] :> (k = r)];

In[10]:= {n, k}

Out[10]= {3 Cos[2 + 4 t], 4}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! There was a very simple solution here. Surprising!

Answer (score 2):

The construction is a little funny, but you could also use `Cases`:

```
Clear[n, k, t]
k = First@Cases[n = 3 Cos[4 t + 2], Cos[r_ t + _] :> r, Infinity]
n
(* {4} *)
(* 3 Cos[4 t + 2] *)
```

I very much like replacement rules with side effects, but I think here it is a little strange. The nice thing about using `Cases` here is that you can strip off the `First`, and then `k` will be set to the list of matches (which would work for the more general case of there being more than one match).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I also thought about this but I wanted to approach in a simpler way.